# Ruby: How do I find provide informative error messages from my gem using caller_locations?

Tags: ruby, error-handling

I have a ruby gem that provides various DSL methods. I'd like to give informative warning messages to the users of my gem, specifically the DSL method in my gem that they called, the file and line of their code, and some other context.

For example:

```rb
# client_code.rb
foo :bar # foo is my DSL method
```

would output a warning to stderr with:

```sh
[WARN] Unexpected option :bar to DSL method 'foo' at client_code.rb:2
```

I would imagine that in my `foo` method I would work with `caller_locations`, but getting a clean solution to this eludes me without comparing system paths and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Ok in writing up this question I discovered a neat solution to this: `Kernel#warn`. It has an `uplevel` option that allows you do what I'm looking for. So in my example, I would do something like:

```rb
def foo(opts)
  warn("Unexpected option :bar to DSL method #{__callee__}", uplevel: 1) if unexpected?(opts)
end
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-warn